# how to make an array containing multiple fields - Arduino

Tags: arrays, encoding, syntax, arduino, record

I am new to arduino and am trying to figure out how to create an indexable array of "records", i.e., each record containing fields, for instance

employee_number int

employee_first_name char string

employee_last_name char string

employee_age int

spouse_age int

etc.

The Arduino reference doesn't seem to address anything except a simple array.

I've searched here and the only thing I find is about someone trying to use an array to address a 4 x 4 keypad.

If Arduino can do such structures, I plan to suggest adding it to the Arduino Structures reference.

Comment: Apparently the same way you would define a struct array in C, e.g. [check here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/defining-a-struct-array/43699).

Comment: https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ and https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-structs-members-and-member-selection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a [struct](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/).

```
struct EmployeeInfo{
  int number;
  char* first_name;
  char* last_name;
  int age;
};

EmployeeInfo employees[3] = {
  {1, "George", "Washington", 23},
  {2, "John", "Adams", 34},
  {3, "Thomas", "Jefferson", 43}
};

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++){

    Serial.print("Number ");
    Serial.println(employees[i].number);
    Serial.print("First Name ");
    Serial.println(employees[i].first_name);
    Serial.print("Last Name ");
    Serial.println(employees[i].last_name);
    Serial.print("Age ");
    Serial.println(employees[i].age);
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!